# Can't get the actual value of a input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was developing a react component to get a value inside a input and automatically show it in a tag, using refs.

All works fine, but the value shown is the previous value.

I really don't now how to fix this. I using the onChange event in the input to change the state of what will be shown, it is clear that the present value is not taken, but rather the previous value

```js
class Conversor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            value: null
        }

        this.output = this.output.bind(this)
    }

    output(){

        console.log(this.state)

        this.refs.output.innerHTML = this.state.value
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.inputValue}</h2>
                <input ref="input" type="text" onChange={() => {this.setState({ value: this.refs.input.value }); this.output()}}/>
                <label ref="output"></label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If i put the value "Hello World" in the input, the value shown is "Hello Worl", when it's have to be the "Hello World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event to do this and no need of `output()` function.

```
class Conversor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            value: null
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.inputValue}</h2>
                <input ref="input" type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({ value: e.target.value });}}/>
                <label ref="output">{this.state.value}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, works fine. but do you know why it's have a diferent result when i, for example, put other function in the onChange atribute?

Comment: The problem in your case is setState() is an asynchronus function, when you call output() function the state might not be updated. What you can do for this is pass your output() function as a callback function to the setState function. `setState({value: e.target.value},()=>{this.output()})`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve your goal is not using the refs. Here is how you do it

```
class Conversor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {};
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
      const { id, value } = e.target;
      this.setState({
        [id]: value
      })
    }

    render() {
      const { name, anotherName } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <input id="name"  name="name" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

                <h2>{anotherName}</h2>
                <input id="anotherName"  name="anotherName" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If you still want to use the `refs` then do the following,

```
class Conversor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            value: null
        }
    }

    output = (e) =>{
        this.setState({value: e.target.value }, () => {
        this.refs.output.innerHTML = this.state.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref="input" type="text" onChange={this.output}/>
                <label ref="output"></label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind your input handler function at all. Instead of doing that, just use an arrow function like *_handleInputTextChange* . Check this out:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class InputTextHandler extends Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           inputValue: ''
       }
   }

   _handleInputTextChange = e => {
       const inputValue = e.target.value;
       this.setState({inputValue})
       console.log(inputValue)
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={this._handleInputTextChange}/>
           </div>
       );
   }
}

export default InputTextHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: grab the event value in the onChange method, and pass the `this.output` method as the second argument to `setState` which fires after the state has been updated which is not a synchronous operation.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{this.state.inputValue}</h2>
            <input ref="input" type="text" onChange={event => {this.setState({ value:event.target.value }, this.output)}}/>
            <label ref="output"></label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/PushySteepEngineering)